# Show that $\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}+\sqrt{4y^2+12yz+5z^2}+\sqrt{4z^2+12xz+5x^2}<=13\sqrt{21}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, means

**question**

Let the real numbers $x,y,z$ be positive nonzeros that fulfil the condition $x+y+z=13$. Show that $\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}+\sqrt{4y^2+12yz+5z^2}+\sqrt{4z^2+12xz+5x^2}<=13\sqrt{21}$.

**idea**

[image]

This was my idea but it didn't lead to a good answer. Still, the number is near and I think we can use what I thought of.

Hope one of you can help me!

Comment: Set x=y=z=13/3 to see the upper bound cannot be lowered. Then try to show that any change in x,y,z makes the sum smaller.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't really understand your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way.

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(2x+y)\sum_{cyc}(2x+5y)}=\sqrt{21}(x+y+z)=13\sqrt{21}.$$

C-S inequality it's the following:

For any reals $a_i$ and $b_i$ prove that:
$$\left(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2\right)(b_1^2+b_2^2+...+b_n^2)\geq(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n)^2.$$
In our case $n=3$:
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x+y)\sum_{cyc}(2x+5y)=\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{2x+y}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{2x+5y}\right)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{2x+y}\cdot\sqrt{2x+5y}\right)\right)^2=\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(2x+y)(2x+5y}\right)^2,$$
which says
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(2x+y)\sum_{cyc}(2x+5y)}.$$

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? I dont understand how you used C-S. Maybe you can do it in steps. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Matei Trandafir I added something. See now.

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

Since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function, by Jensen we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(2x+y)(2x+5y)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2x+y}{3(x+y+z)}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{9(x+y+z)^2(2x+y)(2x+5y)}{(2x+y)^2}}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2x+y}{3(x+y+z)}\cdot\frac{9(x+y+z)^2(2x+y)(2x+5y)}{(2x+y)^2}\right)}=\sqrt{21}(x+y+z)=13\sqrt{21}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\leq\sqrt{21}(x+y+z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{21}x-\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{21x^2-(4x^2+12xy+5y^2)}{\sqrt{21}x+\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)(17x+5y)}{\sqrt{21}x+\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(x-y)(17x+5y)}{\sqrt{21}x+\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}}-\frac{11}{\sqrt{21}}(x-y)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)(21(6x+5y)^2-121(4x^2+12xy+5y^2)}{\left(\sqrt{21}x+\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{21}(6x+5y)+11\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\right)}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-y)^2(17x+5y)}{\left(\sqrt{21}x+\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{21}(6x+5y)+11\sqrt{4x^2+12xy+5y^2}\right)}\geq0$$  and we are done!